# SetState dependent on API response is causing - Too many re-render error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, react-query

In the following code, I'm trying to set the state of `stop` to be true so that on response from a particular API through useQuery, based on a certain code, I can start polling the API. By default the polling remains to be false.

My question is how do I set state here, without react throwing a `Too many re-renders error`

Problem File

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Navigate, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useBffQueryApi } from '../hooks/useQueryBffApi';
import {
  appStatus,
  IStatusAPIResponse,
  IHeaderInformation,
} from '../api/appStatus';
import { useAppSelector } from '../app/hooks';
import { RootState } from '../app/store';
// import { MobileNumber } from './features/ContactNumber/MobileNumber';

export function web() {
  const location = useLocation();
  const authzToken = useAppSelector(
    (state: RootState) => state.authz.AuthzInfo,
  );

  const [stop, setStop] = useState(true);

  const {
    data: response,
    error,
    isLoading,
  } = useBffQueryApi<IStatusAPIResponse, IHeaderInformation>(
    'status',
    () => appStatus({ auth: authzToken }),
    true,
    stop,
  );

  const redirecter = (status: number) => {

//Here lies the problem

    if (status === 306) {
      setStop(false);
      // Do something
    }

//Here lies the problem

    if (status === 41) {
      return <Navigate to="/web/email-confirmation" />;
    }

    if (status === 42) {
      return <Navigate to="/web/personal-details" />;
    }

    if (status === 44) {
      return <Navigate to="/web/address-details" />;
    }

    if (status === 50) {
      return <Navigate to="/web/offer-details" />;
    }

    if (status === 48) {
      return <Navigate to="/web/denied" />;
    }

    if (status === 51 || status === 52 || status === 53) {
      return <Navigate to="/web/offer-details" />;
    }

    if (status === 46) {
      return (
        <Navigate
          to="/web/third-party"
          state={{ location: location.pathname }}
        />
      );
    }

    if (status === 47) {
      return <Navigate to="/web/third-party" />;
    }

    return null;
  };

  if (isLoading) {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Loading</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }

  if (error?.response?.status === 401) {
    return <Navigate to="/web/phone" />;
  }

  const { status } = response!.data;

  return redirecter(status);
}
```

Custom Hook

```
import { AxiosError, AxiosResponse } from 'axios';

export const useBffQueryApi = <J, K>(
  cacheIdentity: string | Array<string | K>,
  fn: QueryFunction<AxiosResponse<J>>,
  enabled: boolean = true,
  stop: boolean = true,
) => {
  return useQuery<AxiosResponse<J>, AxiosError>(cacheIdentity, fn, {
    retry: 0,
    cacheTime: 0,
    enabled,
    refetchInterval: stop ? false : 5000,
  });
};
```

Comment: you are not showing where you call `setStop` - here lies the problem and then no code is shown? Please make sure to post all relevant code!

Comment: @TkDodo I have it. Its in the problem file, in between 2 likes of comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot call setState during render, that violates the rules of react. You are doing that here:

```
if (status === 306) {
  setStop(false);
  // Do something
}
```

side-effects need to go to a `useEffect`, or, you can use the provided `onSuccess` or `onError` callbacks of `useQuery`.

For your case, you wouldn't necessarily need local state, because `refetchInterval` can be a function as well:

```
useQuery(
  key,
  fn,
  {
    refetchInterval: (data) => !data || data.status === 306 ? false : 5000
  }
)
```

Comment: Thanks @TkDodo I was unaware of the same! This really helps :)